# Error while reading a CSV file in Spark - Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a CSV file in Spark - using CSV reader API. I am currently encountering array index out of bound exception.

***Validation:***

```
There is no issue with the input file. All the rows have same number of columns. Column count - 65
```

***Putting below the code that I tried.***

```
sparkSess.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").csv(filePath)
```

Expected result - dataFrame.show()

Actual Error -

```
19/03/28 10:42:51 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: file:///C:/Users/testing/workspace_xxxx/abc_Reports/src/test/java/report1.csv, range: 0-10542, partition values: [empty row]
19/03/28 10:42:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Input Data ::

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|AA|BB|CC|DD|EE|FF|GG|HH|II|JJ|KK|LL|MM|NN|OO|PP|QQ|RR|SS|TT|UU|VV|WW|XX|YY|ZZ|TGHJ|HG|EEE|ASD|EFFDCLDT|QSAS|WWW|DATIME|JOBNM|VFDCXS|REWE|XCVVCX|ASDFF
QW|8|2344|H02|1002|              |1|2019-01-20|9999-12-31|  |EE|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|CNB22345            |IN|9|1234444| |        |        |10|QQ|8|BMX10290M|EWR|   |.000000000|00|M |2027-01-20|2027-01-20| |.00|.00|.00|.00|2014-01-20|1901-01-01|3423.25|  |          |          |      |RE|WW|  |RQ|   |   |   |        |     |        |  | |1901-01-01|0|SED2233345   |2019-01-15 22:10:23|213EDSFDS |78978775|2019-03-23 07:38:34.823000000|        |
```

Comment: can you please share sample csv file content which you are using.

Comment: @KZapagol - added sample data as requested!

Comment: @Dasarathy..I am able read csv file with your sample data.See my updated comment.

Comment: @KZapagol Can u please give header as true & try ?

Comment: @ Dasarathy .. I have tried with header and it's working fine. Please see my updated comment.

Comment: @KZapagol Added another answer to this. Exact point where I was facing issue. Might help you too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use `com.databricks.spark.csv` to read csv files.Please find sample code as below.

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkCSVTest extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("File_Streaming")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .load("C:/Users/KZAPAGOL/Desktop/CSV/csvSample.csv")

  df.show()

}
```

CSV file used:

```
    A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|AA|BB|CC|DD|EE|FF|GG|HH|II|JJ|KK|LL|MM|NN|OO|PP|QQ|RR|SS|TT|UU|VV|WW|XX|YY|ZZ|TGHJ|HG|EEE|ASD|EFFDCLDT|QSAS|WWW|DATIME|JOBNM|VFDCXS|REWE|XCVVCX|ASDFF
QW|8|2344|H02|1002|              |1|2019-01-20|9999-12-31|  |EE|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|CNB22345            |IN|9|1234444| |        |        |10|QQ|8|BMX10290M|EWR|   |.000000000|00|M |2027-01-20|2027-01-20| |.00|.00|.00|.00|2014-01-20|1901-01-01|3423.25|  |          |          |      |RE|WW|  |RQ|   |   |   |        |     |        |  | |1901-01-01|0|SED2233345   |2019-01-15 22:10:23|213EDSFDS |78978775|2019-03-23 07:38:34.823000000|        |
```

With Header :

```
+---+---+----+---+----+--------------+---+----------+----------+---+---+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+---+---+---+---------+---+---+----------+---+---+----------+----------+---+---+---+---+---+----------+----------+-------+---+----------+----------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+-----+--------+---+---+----------+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|  A|  B|   C|  D|   E|             F|  G|         H|         I|  J|  K|         L|         M|         N|                   O|  P|  Q|      R|  S|       T|       U|  V|  W|  X|        Y|  Z| AA|        BB| CC| DD|        EE|        FF| GG| HH| II| JJ| KK|        LL|        MM|     NN| OO|        PP|        QQ|    RR| SS| TT| UU| VV| WW| XX| YY|      ZZ| TGHJ|      HG|EEE|ASD|  EFFDCLDT|QSAS|          WWW|             DATIME|     JOBNM|  VFDCXS|                REWE|  XCVVCX|ASDFF|
+---+---+----+---+----+--------------+---+----------+----------+---+---+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+---+---+---+---------+---+---+----------+---+---+----------+----------+---+---+---+---+---+----------+----------+-------+---+----------+----------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+-----+--------+---+---+----------+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+--------+-----+
| QW|  8|2344|H02|1002|              |  1|2019-01-20|9999-12-31|   | EE|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|CNB22345            | IN|  9|1234444|   |        |        | 10| QQ|  8|BMX10290M|EWR|   |.000000000| 00| M |2027-01-20|2027-01-20|   |.00|.00|.00|.00|2014-01-20|1901-01-01|3423.25|   |          |          |      | RE| WW|   | RQ|   |   |   |        |     |        |   |   |1901-01-01|   0|SED2233345   |2019-01-15 22:10:23|213EDSFDS |78978775|2019-03-23 07:38:...|        | null|
+---+---+----+---+----+--------------+---+----------+----------+---+---+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+---+---+-------+---+--------+--------+---+---+---+---------+---+---+----------+---+---+----------+----------+---+---+---+---+---+----------+----------+-------+---+----------+----------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+-----+--------+---+---+----------+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+--------+-----+
```

Without Header:

```
+---+---+----+---+----+--------------+---+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+----+----+-------+----+--------+--------+----+----+----+---------+----+----+----------+----+----+----------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----------+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------+-----+--------+----+----+----------+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|_c0|_c1| _c2|_c3| _c4|           _c5|_c6|       _c7|       _c8|_c9|_c10|      _c11|      _c12|      _c13|                _c14|_c15|_c16|   _c17|_c18|    _c19|    _c20|_c21|_c22|_c23|     _c24|_c25|_c26|      _c27|_c28|_c29|      _c30|      _c31|_c32|_c33|_c34|_c35|_c36|      _c37|      _c38|   _c39|_c40|      _c41|      _c42|  _c43|_c44|_c45|_c46|_c47|_c48|_c49|_c50|    _c51| _c52|    _c53|_c54|_c55|      _c56|_c57|         _c58|               _c59|      _c60|    _c61|                _c62|    _c63| _c64|
+---+---+----+---+----+--------------+---+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+----+----+-------+----+--------+--------+----+----+----+---------+----+----+----------+----+----+----------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----------+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------+-----+--------+----+----+----------+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|  A|  B|   C|  D|   E|             F|  G|         H|         I|  J|   K|         L|         M|         N|                   O|   P|   Q|      R|   S|       T|       U|   V|   W|   X|        Y|   Z|  AA|        BB|  CC|  DD|        EE|        FF|  GG|  HH|  II|  JJ|  KK|        LL|        MM|     NN|  OO|        PP|        QQ|    RR|  SS|  TT|  UU|  VV|  WW|  XX|  YY|      ZZ| TGHJ|      HG| EEE| ASD|  EFFDCLDT|QSAS|          WWW|             DATIME|     JOBNM|  VFDCXS|                REWE|  XCVVCX|ASDFF|
| QW|  8|2344|H02|1002|              |  1|2019-01-20|9999-12-31|   |  EE|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|2014-01-20|CNB22345            |  IN|   9|1234444|    |        |        |  10|  QQ|   8|BMX10290M| EWR|    |.000000000|  00|  M |2027-01-20|2027-01-20|    | .00| .00| .00| .00|2014-01-20|1901-01-01|3423.25|    |          |          |      |  RE|  WW|    |  RQ|    |    |    |        |     |        |    |    |1901-01-01|   0|SED2233345   |2019-01-15 22:10:23|213EDSFDS |78978775|2019-03-23 07:38:...|        | null|
+---+---+----+---+----+--------------+---+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+----+----+-------+----+--------+--------+----+----+----+---------+----+----+----------+----+----+----------+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----------+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------+-----+--------+----+----+----------+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+--------+-----+
```

**build.sbt**

```
    "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.2",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.2"
```

Screen Shot for Ref. :

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have already tried the same thing. Only difference is the inferschema part.

Comment: And, the same code is working for the other CSV files, flawlessly.

Comment: @DasarathyDR  Does my answer work for you? Still facing any issues?

Comment: I see I have some discrepancy in my input business data itself. Ur answer is right. Because - one particular file read is what is failing for me. Rest all other 3 files work seamlessly.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it is right. I hope it helps! Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190821/discussion-between-dasarathy-d-r-and-kzapagol).

Answer (score 1):

***Just found the exact issue.***

Actually, the 10 CSV files that I was trying to read were UTF-8 format files. Which were NOT causing the issue.
3 Files out of the total 13 files were UCS-2 formatted. Hence these were causing the issue with CSV read process. These files were the ones causing the above mentioned error.

```
UTF-8 ==> Unicode Transformation Format Encoding.
UCS-2 ==> Universal Coded Character Set Encoding.
```

By this, learnt that databricks CSV read supports UTF encoding and causes issues for UCS encoding. Hence, saved the files as UTF-8 format and tried reading the file. It worked like a charm.

Feel free to add more insights on this, if any.

Comment: You can use `charset` option to read file with other encoder. For example if you want to read Shift JS encoder file then you can set charset option as `.option("charset", "Shift-JIS")` .